Как снизить FPS для H264
Необходимо добиться скорости трафика при трансляции с USB камеры, отдающей H264 кадры с частотой 30 fps в разрешении 1920x1080 со скоростью от 6 мбит/c, не более 2 мбит/c, делается это все на слабенькой ARMv7, поэтому вариант пересжатия предельно ресурсоемкий, особенно с учетом того, что не нашел как делать это как GPU Mali.
С учетом того, что базовый функционал выполняется на фрейморвке ffmpeg, возможно ли выполнить снижение частоты кадров БЕЗ потери качества и декодирования в идеале до уровня 10 fps при том же разрешении???

Невозможно, все неключевые кадры зависят друг от друга

разве!? у меня есть только P кадры из неключевых, возможно их как то "складывать" можно!?

Каждый P-кадр зависит от предыдущего I/P кадра, а «складывать» это уже перекодирование

Знаю что по сжатом H264 определяют "вектора движения" без декодирования, возможно есть и способ "сложить" без перекодирования!?

В вопросе стоило бы привести параметры видеопотока. Как вариант, можно попробовать оставлять только опорные кадры, закодированные независимо от других, а остальные просто выкидывать. А если снижение битрейта будет недостаточным, то выкидывать и часть опорных. Кроме того, в мали бывают декодеры и энкодеры h264, так что возможно ваша модель может потянуть и полноценное перекодирование (но с неизбежным снижением качества).

Что касается опорных кадров то они поступают один раз в 1 или 2 секунды в зависимости от моих 2х типов камер, поэтому оставить только опорные кадры никак не получится. Да кодеры аппаратные бывают для Raspberry, но у меня Nano Pi Neo Core, для которого есть сторонний в старой версии ffmpeg кодер cedar, но мне пока не удалось внедрить его в последнюю версию библиотеки.
